# How to safely host many "sites" on a single hostname with XSS protection

Tags: javascript, http, cors, xss, same-origin-policy

I am building a distributed sharing protocol and part of it will be an HTTP/HTTPs proxy that users will run.  The proxy will allow them to access various sites written by other users.  The proxy will also allow the user to interact with those sites via a few API calls.  I expect the sites themselves to be mostly javascript.

So it comes down to, the user has a cookie with:
https://magic-proxy/

The various sites will be at URLs like:
https://magic-proxy/site-a/ (this will contain all the static content of site-a, include javascript, html, css, etc)
and they will submit things to site-a via 
POST https://magic-proxy/site-a/submit

I don't want and javascript on https://magic-proxy/site-b to be able to send a submission to https://magic-proxy/site-a/submit.  Only javascript from site-a should be allowed to do that.

Most of the things I've been reading about CORS and same-origin policies indicate that to browsers, these will be considered the same since they both start with https://magic-proxy

The server answering the HTTP requests will be java and I can send any headers that make sense, but the javascript on these sites will be completely untrusted and probably terrible.

Is there some way to tell the browser that these sites, though they are on the same protocol, port and hostname are really different entities and should be considered different origins?

Comment: my initial thought is to put an auth token into the page which the JavaScript has to send back to auth with and then your server code ensures the token is correct when the submission is made.  You will need to lock down page gets though or else my JavaScript can request the https://magic-proxy/site-a page and grab the token from it.

Comment: @tster I was thinking that, that seems to be what people are doing with antiforgery tokens, but I was worried that site-b could just call the URL in site-a to get the current token.

Comment: No, you will need subdomains.

Comment: The browser isn't designed for this. You will need to host sites as `https://site-a.magic-proxy`, `https://site-b.magic-proxy` etc.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect you guys are right.  For what I am talking about doing this will have to involve a browser extension to remap some hostnames to the proxy or get people to use a SOCKS proxy and relay unrelated traffic to the normal places but some special domains to the proxy service. I don't love either solution.